# Validation (@Valid) of two-dimensional list (List<List<X>>)

Tags: java, validation, jersey, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a class `X`:

```
class X {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private final String name;

    @JsonValue
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public X(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In another class, I have the following:

```
class Input {
    @Valid
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<List<X>> data;
}
```

I am parsing a JSON input file with Jersey and validate with Hibernate Validator. The validation does not seem to be executed - an empty string is accepted.

```
"data": [
  [
    ""
  ],
  [
    "name",
    "location"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own annotiation to check two dimensional list on top of the project:

`https://github.com/jirutka/validator-collection`

It shows how to validate elements in a collection. It could be helpful in your case because **neither jsr303 nor jsr349 gives you possibilty to validate out of the box**

Answer (score 1):

This usecase is not supported by Bean Validation. The `@Valid` annotation on `List<List<X>> data;` will instruct the validator to iterate each `List<X>` element and check for its validity. For this the class `List` will be checked for bean validation constraints, which don't exist (your constraint is on `X`). `@Valid` is not recursive in any form.

A workaround would be to use your own wrapper class to host the list of `X` instances. In this wrapper class you then can annotate the wrapped list with `@Valid`.